# modifying familyName and givenName

Tags: google-api, google-apps

I'm having an issue renaming a user account's familyName and givenName. I'm using the GData API for Python. After running the program no errors are shown. When I print the entryObject it does not show any difference from the original. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

```
import gdata.apps.service

/* email, domain and password are specified here */ 

service = gdata.apps.service.AppsService(email=email, domain=domain, password=password)
service.ProgrammaticLogin()

entryObject = service.RetrieveUser('userAccount')
entryObject.name.familyName = 'lastName'
entryObject.name.givenName  = 'firstName'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was doing things very wrong. I needed to get a different type of UserEntry object. Two relevant links are [UserEntry](http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.apps.multidomain.data.html#UserEntry) and [retrieve_user](http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.apps.multidomain.client.html#MultiDomainProvisioningClient-retrieve_user). These are all done in the gdata.apps.multidomain.client module.

```
import gdata.apps.multidomain.client

email='myemail@domain.com'
password='mypassword'
domain='domain.com'

multiDomainClient = gdata.apps.multidomain.client.MultiDomainProvisioningClient(domain=domain)
multiDomainClient.ClientLogin(email=email, password=password, service='apps', source='mgmt')

entryObject = multiDomainClient.retrieve_user('email@domain.com')
entryObject.SetFirstName('First_Name')
entryObject.SetLastName('Last_Name')
multiDomainClient.update_user('email@domain.com', entryObject)
```